# BARON Optimization Solver on Pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I am trying to install BARON solver on Pyomo + Anaconda. However, I have difficulty linking the solver executables with Pyomo?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Pyomo looks for solvers on your system PATH.

Instructions for how to set the PATH can be found quite easily by Googling "How to set system PATH".

Comment: Do you have a `Dockerfile` to illustrate that?

Comment: I do not. The answer comes from talking to the developers who created the solver interfaces.

Comment: Just make sure that when you run 'baron' from the terminal, it points to something. For me, I run the line `export PATH=/home/romeo/.../baron-lin64:$PATH` that makes sure that the baron executable is available to pyomo.